# Decode binary data in Spark with native column functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, binary, decode

I have an column of type `binary`. The values are 4 bytes long, and I would like to interpret them as an Int. An example DataFrame looks like this:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (Array(0x00.toByte, 0x00.toByte, 0x02.toByte, 0xe6.toByte))
  ).toDF("binary_value")
```

Where the 4 bytes in this example can be interpreted as an U32 to form the number 742. Using a UDF the value can be decoded like this:

```scala
val bytesToInt = udf((x: Array[Byte]) => BigInt(x).toInt)

df.withColumn("numerical_value", bytesToInt('binary_value))
```

It works, but at the cost of using a UDF and corresponding serialization / deserialization overhead. I was hoping to do something like `'binary_value.cast("array<byte>")` and take it from there, or even `'binary_value.cast("int")`, but Spark doesn't allow it.

Is there a way to interpret the binary column to another data type using [Spark native functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be converting to hex (using [**`hex`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#hex(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) and then to dec (using [**`conv`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#conv(num:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,fromBase:Int,toBase:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)).

```scala
conv(hex($"binary_value"), 16, 10)
```

```scala
df.withColumn("numerical_value", conv(hex($"binary_value"), 16, 10)).show()
// +-------------+---------------+
// | binary_value|numerical_value|
// +-------------+---------------+
// |[00 00 02 E6]|            742|
// +-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: That's great! Feels a bit inefficient to go via text, but it's just what I was looking for. I tried to do some benchmarking but didn't find a significant difference. Thanks!